# Evaluate $\int \int \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)}$ $dx dy$ over a triangle with corners (0, 0), (4, 4), and (4, 0) using $x = u$, $y = uv$. Help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration-by-parts

[image]

So far I have:

$$a = x = 4\\ b = y = 0\\ c = y = x$$

$$y=x \rightarrow uv = u\rightarrow v=u/u \rightarrow v=1$$

$$x = 4 \rightarrow u = 4$$

$$y = 0\rightarrow uv = 0 \rightarrow u = 0 \rightarrow v = 0$$

$$\sqrt {(x^2 + y^2)} = (u^2 +uv^2)^{(1/2)}$$
\begin{align}  \|J\| & =det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac {∂x}{∂u}   & \frac{∂x}{∂v} \\
   \frac{∂y}{∂u}   & \frac{∂y}{∂v}\\
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1   & v \\
   0   & u\\
  \end{array} } \right] = u = 4
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{(u^2 + uv^2)} + 4 ~dvdu = \int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{1} (u^2 + uv^2)^{1/2} + 4 ~dvdu
\end{align*}

I can already see this is incorrect due to the given answer.

This gives me J = 0, however J is supposed to = 1? and the answer to the problem is supposed to be:

$$\frac{32(\sqrt2+ln(1+\sqrt2))}3$$

according to the website: https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section15.07.html

Comment: How did you arrive at this $J$?

Comment: I took the partial ∂x/∂u ∂x/∂v of u and ∂y/∂u ∂y/∂v of uv.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: I really think I'm doing this all wrong.

Comment: see edited question @πr8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jacobian is not correct.  It should be $J=u$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^4\int_0^y \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^1\int_0^4 u^2\sqrt{v^2+1}\,du\,dv\\\\
&=\int_0^4 u^2 \,du\,\int_0^1\sqrt{v^2+1}\,dv\\\\
&=\frac{64}{3}\,\left(\frac12\left(\sqrt 2+\log(1+\sqrt 2)\right)\right)\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{32\left(\sqrt 2+\log(1+\sqrt 2)\right)}{3}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: how did you get to the conclusion of $$ u^2 \sqrt {v^2+1}$$

Comment: Tara, note that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=\sqrt{u^2+(uv)^2}\,u\,du\,dv=u^2\sqrt{v^2+1}\,du\,dv$$

Answer (score 0):

By switching to polar coordinates, the wanted integral equals

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\frac{4}{\cos\theta}}\rho^2\,d\rho\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4}{\cos\theta}\right)^3\,d\theta $$
and by using Weierstrass substitution $\theta=2\arctan\frac{t}{2}$ that boils down to
$$ \frac{32}{3}\left(\sqrt{2}+2\,\text{arctanh}\tan\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{32}{3}\left[\sqrt{2}+\log(1+\sqrt{2})\right]}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Why bother switching to polar when one can easily evaluate this in Cartesian only?

Comment: @Dr.MV: actually both approaches are pretty efficient, this is a lucky case :)

Comment: They are indeed.  The one requested by the OP might be the easiest yet.  ;-))